# How do I work around NPN transistor leakage current?

Tags: transistors, led, npn

I am trying to use NPN transistor to switch a 12 V LED strip. Even when there is no voltage applied to base of the transistor the LED strip still flickers a little. I suspect this is because of NPN leakage current. Is there an easy way to mitigate this issue?

Note: The switch is actually Shelly Uni device, but I have tried disconnecting the base completely with no change to the flickering.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWsOty.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: When you say "there is no voltage applied to base of the transistor" do you mean it is open circuit or connected to 0V, the emitter?

Comment: @PeterJennings I mean it's open circuit (either the switch is off or base is completely disconnected). I have edited the schematic to better reflect this.

Comment: What is the current through your LEDs when they are on? What transistor are you using?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I didn't measure the current, but the strip is only about 30cm long and should draw about 300mA. Transistor is S8050

Comment: Are you sure the transistor is connected correctly?  S8050s come in more than one pinout (TO-92). Perhaps the transistor is damaged from overheating (perhaps due to insufficient base current at some time in its life). A typical spec is 100nA maximum Icbo which seems unlikely to cause much flickering.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I do have load on collector side and ground on emitter side but I might have reversed polarity when testing. Do you think the transistor can be damaged?

Comment: @PetrPeller if \$V_{BE}\$ was reverse biased by 12V, there is a very good likelihood that the characteristics of the transistor have been permanently changed (i.e. the transistor is "damaged" in the sense that it will no longer meet its manufacturer's specifications). Excessive leakage current might be one symptom.

Comment: Yes, it's quite possible. Either from Vbe breakdown or overheating as a result of inadequate hFE in the reverse mode.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to connect a resistor from base to ground as shown below.

[image]

This is utilized in a BJT to offer a different path for any leakage current or charge because a BJT will react to even very little currents through the base, making it feasible to partially switch on a load with someleakage current.

Comment: In virtually every case, you should include a current limiting resistor in series with the LED strip unless it already has some built in resistors or constant current devices.